# Showing notification in web app when any mails received in Gmail

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, gmail-api

I want to show the notification in my web app whenever anyone will send the mail to my Gmail account.

I tried to do using IMAP, but IMAP is searching the mails based on the date. Like if I want to search mails from 11-10-2021 then it will give all the mails from 11th date to current date. But suppose I want the mails that comes after 11-10-2021 03:00 Pm, then it is not possible.

Any way to fetch the mails after particular time or based on the UID. Or is there any way to call the webhook whenever any mail receives in the Gmail account?

**Note :** I'm using the codeigniter framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do some settings in your Gmail

On the web
Open Gmail.
At the top right, click Settings. See all settings.
Scroll down to Desktop notifications and select New mail notifications on or Important mail notifications on (if you use Priority Inbox).
Click Save Changes.

let me know if this was useful

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply.

But it would only show me notifications on the desktop of my PC. I want to show that in my web app.

Answer (score 0):

Okay then you need to turn on email notification in outlook

This video will explain everything.

https://youtu.be/Wvksb0VeQKk

Let me know if it helps